# Add an item to a string[] array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have class that has a property that is of type string[].

I need to create another array item, do I have to reset the size and copy all the previous items over?

Comment: This is why there are so many collection classes.

Comment: You might want to add more detail... is this your own code that is of type `string[]`, or is it part of some API that you cannot edit? Which version of C# are you using? (This could invalidate most answers listed here!)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`Array.Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ffy6686%28VS.85%29.aspx) which will preserve the contents of the array.

e.g.

```
var array = myClass.SomeArrayProperty;
Array.Resize(ref array, newSize);
myClass.SomeArrayProperty = array;
```

You need to use a temporary variable because properties cannot be used as `ref` arguments.

Comment: This, internally, basically does a reallocate + copy, though, so it's still a requirement.

Comment: Yes of course; arrays have a fixed size. However the question was "do *I* have to" and the answer is no as this functionality is built in.

Answer (score 6):

If it's *your* class, you should probably change the property to use an `IList<string>`, `ICollection<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>`, depending on how you anticipate this property will be used.  Then, whichever of those you choose to return from the function, try using a `List<string>` in the type itself.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you want to be able to dynamically append items use a `List`.

Although it's a best practice to not expose List as a property, so use `IList<string>` or `IEnumerable<String>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a list if possible. It's a lot easier to manage. Obviously this depends on if it's your class and your able to chance this without any problems.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            myList.Add("item");
            myList.Remove("item");
```

If your having to use arrays then use

[Array.Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ffy6686%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Arrays have fixed size.

From C# specification:

> 12.2 Array creation
>   ...
>   When an array instance is created, the rank
>   and **length of each dimension are
>   established and then remain constant
>   for the entire lifetime of the
>   instance**. In other words, it is not
>   possible to change the rank of an
>   existing array instance, nor is it
>   possible to resize its dimensions.

You may also take a look at blog post from Eric Lippert [Arrays considered somewhat harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer copying the string[] to List<string>, perform all the manipulations, then .ToArray() to produce the resulting string[].

Comment: Wow, that was harsh, and no reasoning why it was such a horrible practice?

Comment: I'm interested to know as well. Perhaps start a new question describing your answer and ask why it's bad?

Comment: Fixt with an upvote. It's a decent solution if the property is a string array that he doesn't own and can't control.

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the class? If so, consider using `List<string>` internally instead.

(And while you're at it, consider using `IList<string>` in your public API instead of `string[]`.)

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to work with `List<T>`, but if you don't control the property this isn't an option. Note that this is seen commonly in soap-generated proxies, but IIRC there is a command-line switch you can use if you prefer lists to arrays.

Note that if you are doing this regularly, an extension method may be helpful:

```
public static T[] Append<T>(this T[] arr, T item) {
    Array.Resize(ref arr, arr == null ? 1 : (arr.Length + 1));
    arr[arr.Length-1] = item;
    return arr;
}
```

Which you can then use for your property:

```
obj.SomeProp = obj.SomeProp.Append(someValue);
```

(note this works even if `obj.SomeProp` is null, creating an array of length 1)

If it were a field/variable, then a simple `ref` argument might also work:

```
public static void Append<T>(ref T[] arr, T item) {
    Array.Resize(ref arr, arr == null ? 1 : (arr.Length + 1));
    arr[arr.Length-1] = item;
}
```